# Why my charging circuit always heat up and malfunction?

Tags: pcb, battery-charging, heat, charging, buck-boost

I am working on troubleshooting bunch of overheating PCBs. I found that 2 components on my charging circuit always heat-up or malfunction even after replacement.

The first problematic component is the Power management chip LTC 4085 which connects the Li-ion battery, voltage converter chip, and the wall adapter. 5V coming from the wall adapter and is passed to the LTC 4085 chip. When the charger is connected, the battery charging voltage is 4.2V from pin 14. When charging is off, the battery voltage is supplied to the converter chip. The problem with this power management chip is, I always get the wrong output on Pin14 to the battery. I have replaced the chip, cleaned up the solder pads underneath but still many failed to have the correct output (either 0V or >4.2V).

The second problematic component is the voltage converter chip TPS63001, convert 5V to 3.3V. This component always heats up. However, it has the correct output. Again, I have tried to replace the components that heat up and clean the solder pad, but the issue is still there.

I have also tried adding a noise filter capacitor on the charging cable to make sure the input voltage is steady around 5V.

Here are the schematics of the design:
[image]

[image][image]

---

Thank you for the responses so far. I am still struggling with this issue.

Here are the link of LTC 4085 and TPS63001 datasheet:

http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/4085fd.pdf

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63002.pdf

I have also tried the following method trying to locate the issue recently:

Increase my R11 to 100Kohms, which connected to Pin12 on U1. This reduces the battery charge current from 1.2A to 500mA.  I previously found out that the recommended charge current for my battery is around 800mA. 1.2A can be too big.. However, after I switched to the 500mA settings. I still get some board to heat up.

Any input will be highly appreciated!

Thanks

---

One more update on the schematics..

The current board doesn't have these components( Q5 and R40 which connect to Pin 11 from the LTC 4085). Can this be a factor of heat up and malfunction issue?

[image]

Comment: Not bothering to try deciphering it, obviously left, right, up and down things are cut off.

Comment: that is not the schematic. ... that is part of the schematic

Comment: Sorry guys, i posted another pic which includes both the charging chip and the buck-boost converter

Comment: "always get the wrong output on Pin14 to the battery... many failed to have the correct output.( either 0v or >4,2v)" - So some boards output 0V, and others >4.2V? This is with the battery disconnected, right? What is the purpose of the diode between BATT and HPWR? "TPS63001... always gets heat up" - exactly how hot does it get? Can you measure the current going into it?

Comment: What's the load on the buck-boost? How hot is it getting?  Did you follow the manufacturer's PCB layout recommendations? What battery are you attempting to charge, do you have a datasheet?

Comment: For the regulator, it's simple. You have not followed the layout requirements. You don't have vias under the chip which the chip is soldered to. See section 10 of the data sheet.

Comment: @seanyu24 "**this design has been working for years**" That new information is important. It means that *something* has changed, to cause the new (problematic) behaviour. And although it is also possible that even when the design *appeared* to be working OK in the past, there may have been a design bug meaning that it was at risk of failing,  *something* has changed to cause this new behaviour - otherwise all previous boards would have also "overheated". I recommend further investigation of the differences between "good" and "bad" boards, including differences which don't *seem* relevant.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Yes, this is with the battery connected.  I haven't looked into that diode yet. It 's a Schottky diode that regulator two input power supply( one from wall adaptor and one from BAT).  The TPS63001 can get pretty hot. sometimes the inductor pads it connected to get melt down... It definitely over the temperature protection limit which cause the unit to shut down during the charging. I only did measure the current going through the U1 , its about 1.0~1.2A max

Comment: @SamGibson, you are right Sam, its the same product but with few different versions... Unfortunately, i only got this one version's schematic... The engineering documents from previous folks are not well maintained. For eg, the current board does not have Q5 connected to the Pin 11 from the LTC 4085.. which will connected with BATT_CHAG pin.

Comment: @JohnD Thank you for replying. Vin on buck-boost is 5.0v. It's getting pretty hot that spread out to whole board and finally shut down the chip because of the overtemperature protection. The design did not strictly follow the recommended layout. For eg, it recommends adding a 100 ohms R3 between Vin and VINA. However, this design has been working for years... I will update the datasheet in my problem statement. Thanks for asking! In addition, the battery is Li-ion battery with 3.7V configuration.( Max 4.2v voltage, 1750mAH and recommend 800mA charging current)

Comment: @seanyu24 - Thanks. Your update: "*eg, the current board does not have Q5 connected to the Pin 11 from the LTC 4085*" suggests the schematic you provided is for the *older*, working, board (because it shows a MOSFET {unreadable designator} connected to LTC4085 pin 11). So that also implies the schematic provided is *wrong* for the *newer*, failing, board. :-( Therefore I cannot trust the information provided and it isn't worth me thinking about this any more. :-( I'll just say that, even if you have to reverse-engineer other PCBs, I would still make a list of the differences. Good luck!

Comment: @SamGibson Thanks for the reminder. I actually go over all the components on the board, these two are the only different/changed parts I found. The other components haven't changed, at least for this section of charging circuit design. The Q5 designator is FDV301N.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast   Thanks for the point! Can you explain what exactly you mean by vias here? I did see one through on my TPS63001 Solder pad. Again, i also go to the page 10 of the TPS 63001 datasheet. I did see the design differs a bit from the recommended settings. However, i haven't found the suggestion of the vias..

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, Sorry for the misunderstanding, i mistook Section 10 as Page 10. Yes, i had gone through section 10 in the past. In our PCB board, we did solder the exposed thermal pads to the soldering pad which had a through hole vias placed in the center position.

Comment: "Yes, this is with the battery connected." - then the battery is either open-circuit or has an internal protection circuit which has disconnected it, because a Li-ion cell will not survive with 0V or >4.2V on it.  "the current going through the U1 , its about 1.0~1.2A max" - the battery is effectively disconnected, so most of that current must be going into the TPS63001. What is the load current?

Comment: @BruceAbbott What i found out is, when the charging voltage from the LTC 4085 is above 4.2v. The charging current is dropped to very low level, which the internal battery can not even being charged. So , i assume there are some open-circuits or malfunction block inside the LTC 4085 chip when its output the abnormal voltage. However, the Li-ion battery should be fine since the current is low. Again, in most cases, the TPS 63001 get heat up first.., However, TPS 63001 only get input voltage/current from the LTC 4085. I am confused it is a thermal design issue or the LTC 4085 issue.